# Finder: All my Files

Tags: finder

I have Outlook 2011 installed, and in the finder "all my files" shows me my e-mail messages, contacts and events. Are these Items saved as files on my mac? can I disable this?

Comment: Yes you can disable the All my Files view. Those are all files saved on your hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

The Finders function "All my Files" will show you all files that are saved on your hard drive.

If you delete them they are deleted. How ever, your email could download them again from the email server (like gmail) if you kept them there.